# Excel formulas and conditional lookups based on multiple criteria and sheets

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, formulas, array-formulas

I have 2 sheets:

- `sheet_a` is a styled print-ready layout for a single data record
- `sheet_b` is a bulk data table which is continually growing. Each row corresponds to a single complete record

Currently I am using a `VLOOKUP` to collect the data from `sheet_b` and put it in the respective cells in `sheet_a`. I have a drop down list on `sheet_a` which allows me to select a single record at a time to view.

Now I want to introduce a second drop down list to sheet_a where I want to select 1 of 4 specific conditions relating to the value of a cell in a specific column of each record on `sheet_b`.

I only want the entries that meet this condition in `sheet_b` to be made available in the range of records I can view on `sheet_a`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you are looking for a way to filter the list that is used in the drop-down on Sheet_A.

- add a column to the source data and calculate or mark manually which of the four conditions the record belongs to.
- on Sheet_a add a drop-down field where the user can select from the four conditions. Name this cell "criterion"
- in the source data table, add a column with a formula that returns the row number if the current row matches the selected criterion. Something like this copied down

  =IF(B2=criterion,ROW(),"")
- create another helper column that contains only the items that match the criterion using a formula like this and copied down

  =INDEX(Data,SMALL($E$2:$E$18,ROW(A1)))
- use a dynamic range name called "FilteredList" that contains only the values of the result list, not the errors. The formula for "FilteredList" is

  =Sheet1!$F$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$F:$F,MATCH("zzzzz",Sheet1!$F:$F,1))
- change the drop-down that is currently used to select a record to source its values from `=FilteredList`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I found instructions to implement something very similar. This method seems a little cleaner though, so I think I will update my implementation. Thanks again!